# Центровка контейнера при адаптиве станицы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не получается отцентровать отдельно labelы, которые находятся в контейнере .tabs. Если обернуть их в отдельный flex-контейнер, то слайдер пропадает. В исходном коде всё находится в одном контейнере .tabs. Я так понимаю, что всё сыпется из-за айдишников labelов, которые определяют инициализацию слайдера в отдельно взятом табе. Я пытался выкрутиться свойством left для .tabs>label, но адаптив при этом работает плохо и ничего хорошего с этого не вышло.

```js
// после готовности DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const contents = {
    "#tab-btn-1": "#content-1",
    "#tab-btn-2": "#content-2",
    "#tab-btn-3": "#content-3"
  };

  const activatedSliders = (selector) => {
    const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    sliders.forEach((slider) => {
      // инициализация elms[i] в качестве слайдера
      if (!slider.classList.contains("activated")) {
        slider.classList.add("activated");
        new ChiefSlider(slider);
      }
    });
  };

  const tabBtns = document.querySelectorAll('[name="tab-btn"]');
  tabBtns.forEach((tabBtn) => {
    tabBtn.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      console.log(e.target);
      const selector = contents["#" + e.target.id] + " .slider";
      activatedSliders(selector);
    });
  });

  activatedSliders("#content-1 .slider");
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider__wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__item {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333333333%;
  max-width: 33.3333333333%;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 7rem;
}

.slider__item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.slider__item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #9c27b0;
}

.slider__item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #3f51b5;
}

.slider__item:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #03a9f4;
}

.slider__item:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.tabs {
  font-size: 0;
  /*max-width: 350px;*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.tabs>input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs>div {
  /* скрыть контент по умолчанию */
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* отобразить контент, связанный с вабранной радиокнопкой (input type="radio") */

#tab-btn-1:checked~#content-1,
#tab-btn-2:checked~#content-2,
#tab-btn-3:checked~#content-3 {
  display: block;
}

.tabs>label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.tabs>label:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-left: none;
}

.tabs>input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Подключаем CSS слайдера -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kilometr-online.com/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/ChiefSlider/chief-slider.min.css">
  <!-- Подключаем JS слайдера -->
  <script defer src="https://kilometr-online.com/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/ChiefSlider/chief-slider.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-1" value="" checked>
  <label for="tab-btn-1">Вкладка 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-2" value="">
  <label for="tab-btn-2">Вкладка 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-3" value="">
  <label for="tab-btn-3">Вкладка 3</label>

  <div id="content-1">
    Содержимое 1...
    <div class="container">

      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider__wrapper">
          <div class="slider__items">
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 1 слайда -->
              1
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 2 слайда -->
              2
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 3 слайда -->
              3
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 4 слайда -->
              4
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 5 слайда -->
              5
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="slider__control" data-slide="prev"></a>
        <a href="#" class="slider__control" data-slide="next"></a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider__wrapper">
          <div class="slider__items">
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 1 слайда -->
              1
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 2 слайда -->
              2
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 3 слайда -->
              3
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 4 слайда -->
              4
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 5 слайда -->
              5
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="slider__control" data-slide="prev"></a>
        <a href="#" class="slider__control" data-slide="next"></a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content-2">
    Содержимое 2...
    <div class="container">

      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider__wrapper">
          <div class="slider__items">
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 1 слайда -->
              1
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 2 слайда -->
              2
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 3 слайда -->
              3
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 4 слайда -->
              4
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
              <!-- Контент 5 слайда -->
              5
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="slider__control" data-slide="prev"></a>
        <a href="#" class="slider__control" data-slide="next"></a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content-3">
    Содержимое 3...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
};
.content-1, .content-2, .content-3{
  width: 100%
}
```

добавьте эти стили и для этих случаев лучше использовать библиотеку, верстка выглядит некрасиво, да и с библиотекой проще).
И у вас не слайдер пропадает, когда вы оборачиваете отдельно элементы, а контент, потому что вы используете радиокнопки и стили из за этого при отображении не видят вложенность, которая указана.
Можно даже не библиотеку, а тупо код найти на js и вставить себе в проект, будет выглядеть и работать намного лучше.
Надеюсь ответила на ваш вопрос

Comment: Кроме того, что теперь весь контент стоит в ряд, ничего не поменялось. Или я просто туплю? Покажите ваш вариант кода, чтобы его можно было здесь запустить.

Comment: @Aleksus https://jsfiddle.net/a40sy8bq/

Comment: Да, конечно. Всё было просто - wrap. Спасибо за прояснение ситуации.